# Error when installing python uinput

Tags: python, installation

I am getting an error when trying to install uinput
I tried PIP and `easy_install`.  I also tried to install 'manually' from tar package.
I always get an error.  Below is the error I get when installing with easy_install.

Can you guide me on how to fix it ?

```
rpi@torpi ~/scripts $ sudo easy_install python-uinput
Searching for python-uinput
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-uinput/
Best match: python-uinput 0.10.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-uinput/python-uinput-0.10.2.tar.gz#md5=abbbbfc50d03a0585a5231d9396f78bd
Processing python-uinput-0.10.2.tar.gz
Running python-uinput-0.10.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ZWLsct/python-uinput-0.10.2/egg-dist-tmp-bPeztQ
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find libudev.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I am running Raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get input to install properly so, I ended up using [evdev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/evdev) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Had this problem and fixed it with

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Comment: Bit of a shame that the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question. This solution worked for me.

Comment: I fixed to with this command but I need to add `--fix-missing` `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing libudev-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is a very old question, but I had the same problem, and running `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` worked for me. Also, make sure to run pip with sudo.